# Overriding Admin shapes in custom Orchard CMS theme

Tags: admin, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchardcms-1.8

I'm doing a custom theme for Orchard CMS.

As part of client project one of the requirements is to have some extra functionality in blog admin page.
This is pretty easy doing some simple changes in Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.ListAdmin.cshtml

I do not want to change the Blog source code, I would like to override that wiew in theme just like I'm doing with all the others on front end.

Following some guidelines found on orchard forum I have tried the following paths:

```
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.ListAdmin.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Orchard.Blogs/Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.ListAdmin.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Dashboard/Admin/Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.ListAdmin.cshtml
```

but the view is not picked up.

So, How may I override a view in my theme that will be picked up by admin dashboard instead of the default one?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a theme with a project file, then add a .cs file with something like this in it:

```
public class AdminOverride : IThemeSelector
{
    public ThemeSelectorResult GetTheme(RequestContext context)
    {
        if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(context))
        {
            return new ThemeSelectorResult { Priority = 111, ThemeName = "NewAdminTheme" };
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't set this theme as current though, just enable it from the backend. You will also need to set your TheAdmin as the base theme in the Theme.txt like this:

```
BaseTheme: TheAdmin
```

Comment: Ok. I have tried it. If I do with the current (frontend) theme I'm coding, the frontend takes over to the whole admin theme: not what I want. If I create a new admin theme and I put there your code and just the modified view it works (the view) but it does not falls back to admin (so no css, no admi views,... pretty bare). So to make it working I have to copy ALL the current admin theme to new theme, then I have to add my changes and your code. This way works BUT I have duplicated the Admin Theme... It sounds to me as  a sort of workaround...

Comment: Any suggestion to just override the single view without duplicate all the related stuff?

Comment: Just set BaseTheme: TheAdmin in your Theme.txt file

Comment: But yes, it is a sort of workaround, Orchard doesn't really offer any way of extending the admin theme unfortunately

Comment: PERFECT!. This was the last missing piece. BaseTheme is exactly what transforms your tip in a solution... this way I can create my admin theme that overrides just what I need and if AdminTheme is updated I have no need to update mine.

Comment: btw: your twitter account on profile seems wrong... it takes to a 404 page... ;)